# Laravel Angularjs Nginx configuration

Tags: php, angularjs, nginx, laravel-5

I need to deploy my Laravel and Angularjs application on same server.
Urls starting with /api/ should go to my php server and look into route.php and all the rest should be served from angular.

The Angular app is working fine.
But the /api/ urls are not reaching to my route.php

Here is my Nginx configuration file:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name my-project.com;
    root /var/www/my-project.com/web/my-project/Client/app;

    index index.html index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    location /api/ {
        alias /var/www/my-project.com/web/my-project/Server/public/;

        index index.php;
    }

    error_log  /var/log/nginx/example.com-error.log error;
}
```

If I prepend /api/ to my routes, it gives 404, and if I don't, it provides index.html in my response.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How are you connecting nginx to your php server?